How can I use a SHAP explainer for a Keras model trained on inputs of different dimensions?
I have trained a Keras model on 6 different inputs, each of different dimensions (3 of the inputs are sequence datasets, of size 4 by the max sequence length, and 3 of the inputs are simple integers). While everything works when training and testing the model, I cannot use these inputs when trying to build a SHAP explainer.
I keep getting the error when running explainer.shap_values(list_of_test_inputs):
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
I'm trying to figure out what the appropriate way to pad my data is for this error--should I retrain my model on inputs of all the same shape if I would like to use SHAP? Is there a workaround so that I can continue to use the same 6 inputs already trained on?
My end goal is to gain an understanding of relative feature importance between the 6 input features, and develop a heatmap for each of the sequence inputs of relative importance to the model.
